# How to duplicate records based on N values in spark scala

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I have the dataframe like in below format.

| A | B | n |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2 | 1 |
| 2 | 9 | 1 |
| 3 | 8 | 2 |
| 3 | 10 | 4 |

I am trying to duplicate record based on n columns value as 3rd row value of n = 2 that means it would be duplcate 2 times like

| A | B | n |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2 | 1 |
| 2 | 9 | 1 |
| 3 | 8 | 2 |
| 3 | 8 | 2 |
| 3 | 10 | 4 |
| 3 | 10 | 4 |
| 3 | 10 | 4 |
| 3 | 10 | 4 |

I am trying to do this in scala spark using explode function but unable to do .

I am editing for further comments for increment by 1 in n values like

| A | B | n |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2 | 1 |
| 2 | 9 | 1 |
| 3 | 8 | 2 |
| 3 | 8 | 3 |
| 3 | 10 | 4 |
| 3 | 10 | 5 |
| 3 | 10 | 6 |
| 3 | 10 | 7 |

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can explode an array_repeat:

```
df.withColumn("n", explode(array_repeat($"n", $"n"))).show
+---+---+---+
|  A|  B|  n|
+---+---+---+
|  1|  2|  1|
|  2|  9|  1|
|  3|  8|  2|
|  3|  8|  2|
+---+---+---+
```

For your edited question,

```
df.withColumn("n", explode(sequence($"n", $"n"*2-1))).show
+---+---+---+
|  A|  B|  n|
+---+---+---+
|  1|  2|  1|
|  2|  9|  1|
|  3|  8|  2|
|  3|  8|  3|
|  3| 10|  4|
|  3| 10|  5|
|  3| 10|  6|
|  3| 10|  7|
+---+---+---+
```

Comment: not working , if there are few row with n =3,4,5

Comment: @Dev sorry, misunderstood the question. See edit?

Comment: its working fine , can we increment column value n from n to value of n in next rows, suppose N = 2, then next N will be 2,3
if N=5 then ,N=5,6,7,8,9,10.

Comment: same as your previous deleted answer but not start from lit(1), i should be like current value of N to number of N value.

Comment: @Dev I'm confused. Do you want it from n to 2*n? You can try `explode(sequence($"n", $"n"*2))`

Comment: No just wants to change the Value of N , increment by 1 , i am adding new row in my question for more ..

Comment: Please check last table in edit question.

Comment: @Dev you can explode from n to 2n-1